# how to get the value from this json response using php

Tags: php

i need to extract  the `exam` from this json response using php

```
cb({"data": [{"map": {"exam": ["e", "x", "a", "m"]}, "words": false, "o": ["exam", "exam", "exam"]}]},150)
```

Comment: Which `exam`? I see four of them, possibly five.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the answer is wrapped in a callback function `cb()` which is not valid JSON. The JSON part is the parameter that is passed to this function (everything between and including `{...}`). So the first step is to remove this "outer function":

```
$json = trim($json, 'cb(),150');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$exam = $json['data'][0]['map']['exam'];
```

Reference: [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), [`json_decode`](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), [`arrays`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

This only works if the number at the end only consists of 1, 5 or 0. You can either add all digits to the second parameter of `trim` or use a combination of [`strripos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) and [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to chop off everything after `}`.